# Azure Instance Communication while Auto Scaling

Tags: c#, azure, server, azure-web-app-service, autoscaling

While having a Web App that autoscales to say 1 or 10 instances - how can you handle such events as "New Instance" (when the server load increases) and "Instance Closed" (when the server load decreases) then get the current ID (or any info) of that instance to support some 3rd party tools to support scaling. At the moment, some 3rd party tools do alot of the work behind the scenes but although they support scaling - they need some information on how to be configured.

If the instances can communicate - how do they do it and how does that work and how to be able to use that information for any other services to also support scaling?

How does Instance A communicate to Instance B that A is doing something so B shouldn't do it - or anything like that.

Any coding suggestions or examples on how this work?

Comment: Yes. You would use internal endpoints. Please check this stackoverflow.com/questions/16323767/azure-network-communication-between-instances-of-the-same-role

Comment: if you are running your app on Azure App Service, i don`t think you will be able open internal port like Roles in Cloud Services. you will have to use external persistent storage like "Azure Queue/Table Storage" to exchange status